# Infinite life cycle service android

Tags: android

I call a Service in Activity, but when i close the application, the services are closed. How I create a infinite life cycle service? And, how I call a Activity in the BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I create a infinite life cycle service?

You can't. The OS will terminate your process when it sees fit, which includes terminating it when the user asks, such as via a task killer application. Please design your application with this in mind.

> And, how I call a Activity in the BroadcastReceiver?

If the `BroadcastReceiver` was registered by the activity, via `registerReceiver()`, then if the `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of the activity, it can just call methods on the activity normally, just like any inner class in Java.

Comment: But when I call BroadcastReceiver on BOOT_COMPLETE and start a service inside of this BroadcastReceive. The service keeps running infinitely.

Comment: @Vinix: No, it does not. As I wrote, the OS will terminate your process when it sees fit, which includes terminating it when the user asks, such as via a task killer application.

Comment: Ok, what I really need is that every 10 minutes, process a HTTPRequest in background, without UI. This is possible?

Comment: @Vinix: Certainly, but not by having an "infinitely" running service. Use `AlarmManager` to get control every 10 minutes. If you are using a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm with it (to wake up the device every 10 minutes, even if it is in sleep mode), use my `WakefulIntentService` to do the actual downloading work: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create such a thing.

The closest thing you can do is to set your service into foreground, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Service keep running after stopping the Activity, start it via startService instead of bindService. Don't forget to stop it again.

startActivity to start an Activity
sendBroadcast to start a BroadcastReceiver
startService to start an Activity.

Comment: But within 30 seconds it stops working, without call onStop or onDestroy.

Comment: If Android likes it, it will kill it. For example for resources.